# Selecting similar DOM elements without ids

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm building a web scraper.

I'd like to be able to select one link on the page and querySelectAll for other links that are similar.  Here's the path I've gotten by select one link: `body > table:nth-child(4) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+2) > p > font > a`

I could just select the other based on `td>p>font>a` but the issue is that the paths will change and I won't know the nested structure ahead of time.  Sometimes it might be tables, other times divs.

How should i go about searching the DOM and dynamically selecting similar elements based on my my current selection?

Comment: You know how selectors work, so you'll just need to compose a valid string. I don't know what other answer you expect to be honest.

Comment: What does "*similar*" mean?